# Tags not responsive in locust

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, performance-testing, locust

I have two challenges:

1. I am trying to use `--tags` in `docker-compose.yml` but it isn't working, here's a snippet

```
    @tag('get_all_themes')
    @task
    def get_all_themes(self):
        self.client.get('/atlasnextgen/public-api/v1/themas',
                        headers={"Authorization": f"Basic {auth}"})

    @tag('get_themes_uuid')
    @task
    def get_themes_by_uuid(self):
        self.client.get(f'/atlasnextgen/public-api/v1/themas/{uuid}',
                        headers={"Authorization": f"Basic {auth}"})
```

And the command in docker-compose.yml is: `-f /mnt/locust/public_apis/themes.py --master -u 50 -r 10 -t 60s --headless --print-stats --csv /mnt/locust/reports/csv/result_for --csv-full-history --html /mnt/locust/reports/html/docker_loadtest_result.html --tags get_all_themes`
Please what am I doing wrong?

2. How can I run commands in a docker-compose file such that I can use specific tags per command?